# What are the use cases for assignment with duplicate index in R?

Tags: arrays, r

It's seems that when making assignment in R using subsetting it is possible to use multiple time the same index. For example:

```
> a <- 1:4
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4
> index <- c(2,2,2)
> index
[1] 2 2 2
> val <- 5:7
> val
[1] 5 6 7
> a[index] <- val
> a
[1] 1 7 3 4
```

Is there an OFFICIAL R rule that describes what is the executed result after the assignment ? Is a[2] == 5 ? or 6 ? or 7 ? (My R version 3.2.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 implementation give 7 as the answer)

But what are the use cases for duplicate index in assignment ? Why is it possible ?

Comment: I guess you need `a[unique(index)] <- val[unique(index)]`

Comment: I don't think you'll find a formal specification for what happens in this case, if only because there isn't a (complete) formal specification for the R language. That said, I can't think of any practical use cases for this -- it seems like more of a curiosity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hong Ooi, i think a GPU optimized implementation of R (with hardware vectorization) couldn't be deterministic in such case (answer could vary because it is a concurrent access).

Comment: That's a very good point re GPU implementation. Of course there isn't such an implementation right now, but in principle there could be.

Answer (score 1):

With `a[index] <- val` in your example you are changing `a[2]` three times, first it is assigned the value 5, then 6, and finally 7.

In other words, owing to vectorization, the command `a[index] <- val` is equivalent to the sequence of commands:

```
a[2] <- val[1]
a[2] <- val[2]
a[2] <- val[3]
```

As a result, you only see the last value that has been assigned to `a[2]`, which is 7 in this case.